# Sony SW2 RegistrationInformation

Tags: android, sony-smartwatch

I'm trying to register a new app is developed by myself but it doesn't appear on the SmartWatch 2 tablet app. I'm sure that the app tries to register because it reach the `public ContentValues getExtensionRegistrationConfiguration()` part of the code but I don't know what the problem is.

This is my code:

```
@Override
public ContentValues getExtensionRegistrationConfiguration() {
    String extensionIcon = ExtensionUtils.getUriString(mContext, R.drawable.icon_extension);
    String iconHostapp = ExtensionUtils.getUriString(mContext, R.drawable.icon);
    String extensionIcon48 = ExtensionUtils.getUriString(mContext, R.drawable.icon_extension48);

    String configurationText = mContext.getString(R.string.configuration_text);
    String extensionName = mContext.getString(R.string.extension_name);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.CONFIGURATION_ACTIVITY,
            TactileComPreferenceActivity.class.getName());
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.CONFIGURATION_TEXT, configurationText);
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.EXTENSION_ICON_URI, extensionIcon);
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.EXTENSION_48PX_ICON_URI, extensionIcon48);
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.EXTENSION_KEY, getExtensionKey());
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.HOST_APP_ICON_URI, iconHostapp);
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.NAME, extensionName);
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.NOTIFICATION_API_VERSION,
            getRequiredNotificationApiVersion());
    values.put(Registration.ExtensionColumns.PACKAGE_NAME, mContext.getPackageName());

    return values;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your registration code looks fine.  Couple things to check:

1. Does your app appear in SmartConnect on the tablet?
2. Have you tried running any of the sample apps?  Are you able to install/run those?

Comment: The app appears on the tablet but only on the installed apps not in the SmartConnect. I've tried running the sample apps and it works fine. Actually if I copy my app code to one of the samples I can run my app but of course with the name and logo of the sample code

Comment: Sounds like you are missing something else in the registration process.  Maybe try starting with a sample code project and copy all of your app code in there might be the easiest.

Comment: I've tried to do that and using HelloLayouts as the base I got an odd result. If I install the HelloLayout sample and after that I change the code I get my app running but If after change the code I try to reinstall it I get the same issue.

Comment: I still having this problem, any more ideas? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running on other devices to see if the issue still occurs?  Which tablet is this exactly?  Have you tried running on any phones?

Comment: It's a Samsung Galaxy TAB 2 10.1 with android 4.2.2. I've tried to run it on a phone and I had the same issue